# Validate date for a week

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am fresher and I don't know how to solve below issue.

I have date and i want to allow user to go next if that date is in week. Means I want 7 days validation. If date is after 8 days then don't allow user to go next.Thank you if anybody solve this issue.

Comment: So you want to know how to do arithmetic with dates?  Have you researched that at all?  NSCalendar?  NSDateComponents?

Comment: If I understood right You want to check if the selected date is in current week or not?

Comment: @arturdev No. I want to check - from current date to my date (which is next date from current date) are having 7 days distance or not.

Answer (score 4):

This function check if a given date is in the current week.

```
- (BOOL)isDateInThisWeek:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    int weekday = [comps weekday];
    int validDays = 7-weekday;

    comps = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:today toDate:date options:0];
    int days = [comps day];

    BOOL inThisWeek = days <= validDays;
    return inThisWeek;
}
```

First calculate the weekday of today and the remaining days this week, then check the number of days between today and the given date is <= of the remaining days.

Comment: @jberlanaL: Hi, My app is crashing because of different dateTime format.I tried to change format of my date but it's not changing and app is crashing..Is there any other solution for this.

   today =2014-11-27 07:22:14 +0000 Date =2014-11-29T20:30:00+00:00

Answer (score 1):

Set the maximum date as date after 7 days from today.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps = [NSDateComponents new];
comps.day = 7;
NSDate *sevenDays = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
dpDob.maximumDate = sevenDays ;
```

If you want to add validation then you can add this

```
 NSDate* dateTodate = [NSDate date];;

 NSTimeInterval distanceBetweenDates = [dateTodate timeIntervalSinceDate:sevenDays];
 double secondsInAnHour = 3600;
 NSInteger hoursBetweenDates = distanceBetweenDates / secondsInAnHour;
 if(hoursBetweenDates>168)
{
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:GENERAL_Title message:
                                  @"Select a date within 7 days from today" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:
                                  @"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
  [alert show];

}
```

Comment: `double secondsInAnHour = 3600;` is not  *always* **TRUE**. Sorry but I couldn't stop myself to comment, this will help you to learn

Comment: Why this is not always true? Tell me the reason

Comment: Lead seconds dear...

Comment: Thats not an issue.. we can calculate the same as sec :)

Comment: any link to support your words, plz....

Comment: No need of link.. simple mathematics it is

Comment: **NO** playing with dates are not simple mathematics. Its like every Feb doesn't have 28 or 29. There are leap seconds, hours, years etc.... if you dont trust my words, see my profile 60+ answers on NSDate, Have earned Bronze badge for NSDate etc

Comment: and check if(hoursBetweenDates>604800){  }

Comment: no no no.... see other answer raised to +3 you are still +1. And that +1 is by the OP only.

Answer (score 1):

See `- (BOOL) isThisWeek` method
https://github.com/erica/NSDate-Extensions/blob/master/NSDate%2BUtilities.m